# How to make chosen dropdownlist be above all other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-chosen

HTML:

```
<div style="overflow: auto; position: relative; z-index: 99999999 ! important;" class="content">
    <h4>Filter</h4>
    <div style="overflow: visible; width: 100%; padding: 0 0 3% 0;">
        <!-- the DDL is here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  /* ----------- */
  .content {
      background: #FFF;
      border-top: 2px solid #00539B;
      padding: 2em;
      min-height: 115px;
      /*height: 220px;*/
  }

  .content h2,
    .content h3,
    .content h4,
    .content p {
      margin: 0 0 15px 0;
      color: #00539B;
  }
```

How can I modify the style in my page or the chosen CSS/JQuery to make it appear outside and over every other DIV on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You should do some DOM manipulation:

```js
$('#child').css({
  left:10,
  top:25
}).appendTo(document.body);
```

```css
div{width:300px; height:150px; overflow:hidden; background:red;}
#child{width:150px; height:250px; overflow:hidden; background:yellow; left:20px; top:50px; position:absolute;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Parent
  <div id='child'>Child</div>
</div>
```

---

The elements appears at the closing of body they can be shown on top of every other elements.

Comment: Actually that is a good solution but won't work in my case. Thank you any way.